# Symfony 2: Create overview page with possibility to search - always got errors from form "should not be blank"

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I defined the form:

```
class OrganizationSearchType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name', 'text', array('label' => 'Name', 'required' => false))
            ->add('category', 'text', array('label' => 'Kategorie', 'required' => false))
            ->add('street', 'text', array('label' => 'Strasse', 'required' => false))
            ->add('zip', 'text', array('label' => 'PLZ', 'required' => false))
            ->add('city', 'text', array('label' => 'Ort', 'required' => false))
            ->add('search', 'submit', array('label' => 'Suchen'));

    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'organization';
    }
}
```

TWIG: {# app/Resources/views/organization/overview.html.twig #}

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    <h2>Organistationen</h2>
    {{ form_start(searchForm) }}
    {{ form_errors(searchForm) }}
    <div>
        {{ form_label(searchForm.name) }}
        {{ form_widget(searchForm.name) }}
    </div>
    <div>
        {{ form_label(searchForm.category) }}
        {{ form_widget(searchForm.category) }}
    </div>
    <div>
        {{ form_label(searchForm.street) }}
        {{ form_widget(searchForm.street) }}
    </div>
    <div>
        {{ form_label(searchForm.zip) }}
        {{ form_widget(searchForm.zip) }}
    </div>
    <div>
        {{ form_label(searchForm.city) }}
        {{ form_widget(searchForm.city) }}
    </div>

    {{ form_end(searchForm) }}

    {% if searchDone %}
    {% if table|length > 0 %}
```

Conroller:

```
/**
     * @Route("/organization")
     */
    public function showAll(Request $request)
    {
        $searchOrganization = new Organization();
        $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Organization');
        $availableCategories = $repository->getDistinctCategories();

        $selectCategories = array();
        for ($i=0; $i<count($availableCategories); $i++) {
            array_push($selectCategories, $availableCategories[$i]['category']);
        }

        $searchForm = $this->createForm(new OrganizationSearchType(), $searchOrganization);
        $searchForm->remove('category');
        $searchForm->add('category','choice', array('choice_list' => new ChoiceList($selectCategories, $selectCategories), 'label' => 'Kategorie', 'required' => false));
        $searchForm->handleRequest($request);

        if ($searchForm->isSubmitted()) {
            $name = $searchForm["name"]->getData();
            $category = $searchForm["category"]->getData();
            $street = $searchForm["street"]->getData();
            $zip = $searchForm["zip"]->getData();
            $city = $searchForm["city"]->getData();

            $searchOrganization = $repository->getBasicSearch($name, $category, $street, $zip, $city);
        } else {
            $searchOrganization = '';
        }

        return $this->render(
            'organization/overview.html.twig',
            array(
                'table' => $searchOrganization,
                'searchForm' => $searchForm->createView(),
                'searchDone' => $searchForm->isSubmitted(),
            )
        );
    }
```

All fields are optional - if they have no content the like-Statement searches for '%'. But I always get Errors - cannot find a possiblity to remove them.

```
category [choice]

Errors

Message Origin  Cause
This value should not be blank. category    Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintViolation
Object(Symfony\Component\Form\Form).data.category = null

city [text]

Errors

Message Origin  Cause
This value should not be blank. city    Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintViolation
Object(Symfony\Component\Form\Form).data.city = null
```

Class Organization:

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Entity/Product.php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Entity\OrganizationRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="organization")
 */
class Organization
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=150)
     */
    protected $name;

    /** 
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    protected $category;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank() 
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    protected $street;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=20)
     */
    protected $zip;

    /**
     * @Assert\NotBlank()
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
     */
    protected $city;

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set name
     *
     * @param string $name
     * @return Organization
     */
    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * Set category
     *
     * @param string $category
     * @return Organization
     */
    public function setCategory($category)
    {
        $this->category = $category;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get category
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getCategory()
    {
        return $this->category;
    }

    /**
     * Set street
     *
     * @param string $street
     * @return Organization
     */
    public function setStreet($street)
    {
        $this->street = $street;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get street
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getStreet()
    {
        return $this->street;
    }

    /**
     * Set zip
     *
     * @param string $zip
     * @return Organization
     */
    public function setZip($zip)
    {
        $this->zip = $zip;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get zip
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getZip()
    {
        return $this->zip;
    }

    /**
     * Set city
     *
     * @param string $city
     * @return Organization
     */
    public function setCity($city)
    {
        $this->city = $city;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get city
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getCity()
    {
        return $this->city;
    }
}

class OrganizationRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function getBasicSearch($name, $category, $street, $zip, $city) {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('organization');
        if ($name == '') {
            $name = '%';
        }
        if ($category == '') {
            $category = '%';
        }
        if($street == '') {
            $street = '%';
        }
        if($zip == '') {
            $zip = '%';
        }
        if($city == '') {
            $city = '%';
        }
        $qb->where(
            $qb->expr()->andX(
                $qb->expr()->like('organization.category', ':category'),
                $qb->expr()->like('organization.name', ':name'),
                $qb->expr()->like('organization.street', ':street'),
                $qb->expr()->like('organization.zip', ':zip'),
                $qb->expr()->like('organization.city', ':city')
            )
        )->setParameters(array('category' => $category, 'name' => $name, 'street' => $street, 'zip' => $zip, 'city' => $city));

        $res = $qb->getQuery();
        return $res->getResult();
    }

    public function getDistinctCategories() {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('organization');
        $qb->select(array('organization.category'));
        $qb->addGroupBy('organization.category');
        $qb->orderBy('organization.category');
        $res = $qb->getQuery();
        return $res->getResult();
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have an entity binded to form?

Comment: Could you add the `Organization` class to the question?

Comment: Added the class "Organization"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error come from the assertion onto your entity

```
/** 
 * @Assert\NotBlank()
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
 */
protected $category
```

Regardless what you put onto your form, every time you call `isValid()` onto a form tied to an entity, entity assertions are checked aswell. And this perfectly make sens.

You have to fix your code

- remove assertion(s) from your entity
- remove `required => false` from your `FormType`

Moreover, you're doing some extra work that isn't necessary and you're doing it in the wrong way.

- If you tie an object to a form, you don't need to retrieve data from form directly
- If you want to make a list of available category, you can hadle it passing an entitymanager to your FormType and, if you need, there's the possibility to set default values.

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

Why do you remove then add the category field?

I think that is the problem. You should pass the required parameters through the constructor or a setter method and initialize the form corretly for the first time.

Comment: I remove the text-field and add a select-box for category. But this is not the problem... same problem exists e.g. for city.

  city [text]

  Errors

  Message Origin Cause
  This value should not be blank. city       Symfony\Component\Validator\ConstraintViolation
  Object(Symfony\Component\Form\Form).data.city = null

Comment: Added the city example also - all fields should be able to deal with "blank values". Functionallity is already fine - just got these errors in the Profiler.